# MariaDB Inserts are getting slower and slower (7x tables, ~ 2.8M and 200MB)

Tags: mariadb

I have auto increment on each of a table.
One unique ID that is consistent of 10 numbers, and each table have ~ 6 big int columns (values are small from 1-60k), and from 0 to 4 var chars (~ up to 500 characters, on average from 5 to 50 characters).

Quickly tested and with fresh database (dump and clean all tables) I started with 1000/s, then within seconds dropped to 400 => 200/s, after ~ just 116MB & ~ 500k records in 5 main tables it dropped to 159/s and keeps dropping. (memory usage 1.6%, disk writes ~ 1.2MB/s, reads => 0B/s).

Removed all other keys other than auto increment, so not sure why it is so slowing down.

This is nothing as I've worked with DB that was holding trillions of columns and auto increment and huge varchars. (however paid solution :().

I already tweaked the config so many times but still getting to the point where server is using ~ 950% & .net core 25% (of all cores).

Machine has i9 9900k 8c/16t, 64GB RAM, 2x NVME 2TB

I can't even run @ 5 minute API test as it won't be able to process all data from a queue :( (API can accept ~ 20k/s).

Buffers, read io, inno_db other tweaks for a commit etc. were applied, nothing seems to be working.

Looks like it cannot for some reason handle just so little data and I cannot figure out why (I never had any real experience with free databases, so I only assume that it should be able to insert 300k records within 60 seconds and sustain this for ~ 10TB).

Comment: You have written a lot of words, but they hole very little info.  If indexes are involved, we need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the DML statements.  If ram is at 100%, what is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  Are you using InnoDB?  "Trillions of columns" sounds like a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel embarrassed :/, turned out that there were missing important indexes :(

Run for around night with ~ 1800k/s inserts (for endpoint, from mysql there would be probably 6 inserts + 4 reads for each endpoint insert, so ~ 10k/s of inserts + 8k/s reads).

In total over 150M records were created, > 30GB of data, no slow downs, still going fast.

RAM usage ~ 100% that was set for MySQL (32GB).

Really happy with it now :)

Of course replication will be another though decision, but for anyone else.

Make sure that proper indexes are in place, performance here degrade quickly.

Comment: RAM usage at 100% -- Beware!  If it starts swapping, performance will go down drastically.

Comment: "RAM usage ~ 100% that was set for MySQL (32GB)." please read the whole sentence. Server has 128GB.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a too far-fetched guess, but I don't have access to comments yet and decided to post as an answer even if it's more of a request for additional info.

Do the tables in question use MyISAM storage engine or InnoDB? You may check by

```
show create table <table_name>;
```

If it's MyISAM then you need to increase key_buffer_size param, not innodb_* ones.